# When closing an FTP session, is there any benefit to logging out (QUIT) before disconnecting?

Tags: java, ftp

I'm using the Apache Commons `FTPClient`, so this would be the `logout` and `disconnect` methods respectively. I understand that `logout` is useful where you want to log back in as a different user on the same connection; that's not the case here.

The `ftp4j` docs mention that some servers don't implement logout at all, so I'd guess that it's redundant here, but I wondered if a "rude" disconnect might potentially leave dangling sessions on the server.

Comment: Might avoid errors on the server side.  Its easy, why not do it.

Comment: @Yetti99 - it's easy in the mainline case, but it makes error handling uglier. Instead of just calling `disconnect` in a `finally` or equivalent, you need to keep track of whether you've logged in successfully, and make sure that if `logout` throws you still call `disconnect`, and worry about what on earth a `false` returnvalue from `logout` means. None of which is particularly difficult, it's just messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it is not a problem to just close the connection as long as no data connection is still open. But don't underestimate the creativity of programmers to abuse features. I've once had to do with a FTP server which started a transaction at log in and committed it on QUIT. If you just closed the connection instead of doing the QUIT a rollback was done and all uploaded files were lost.

Apart from that, QUIT can not be used to logout and log in again, because the server will close the control connection after the QUIT. So you have to reconnect anyway.